# How to read data from USB Device dynamically

Tags: android, usb

I have an app that take pictures from USB Cameras. The problem is, I want to take pictures using the usb camera button, instead of a button on my android.

I found out that the usb camera button when pressed sends to the usb host a 'S' string.

I want to be able to know when the user pressed this button by reading the 'S' string.

I know android has the USB API, but what I found so far tells me how to read data from USB, but note that what I want is to get the event of when the usb device is trying to send me something and then read it.

Is there any way to do it?

Ps - I am already able to connect to the USB device and open it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who had the same problem, I find out myself:

Since the message the usb device was sending is a String, what I did was to create an EditText with background and textColor Transparent in the activity I wanted to receive the msg and let it selected.

So when I pressed the button and the usb device sent the 'S' string it was copied in the EditText text.

Adding a TextChangedListened solved the problem.

It's not pretty, but it worked.

```
editS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextS);
editS.setSelection(0);


editS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(s.length() != 0){
                editS.setText("");

                if (mHandler.isCameraOpened()) {
                    mHandler.captureStill();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "NO_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```